# OffsetDateTime.toString() removes seconds and nanoseconds when they are 0

Tags: java

For example when I am trying to print such OffsetDateTime:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2018, 3, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

output is:

```
2018-03-18T00:00Z
```

instead of

```
2018-03-18T00:00:00.000Z
```

Maybe you know are there any easier way to do it then implement own toString/converter method?

Answer (score 3):

From Java API: format(DateTimeFormatter formatter) Formats this date-time using the specified formatter.

I would guess the easiest for you would be to use:

```
OffsetDateTime.of(2018, 3, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in such case we will lost nano secs if they are 0. I found another approach: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnnX"). In this case nano secs will not be removed from representation. Thanks

Comment: ah sorry I saw the seconds but I forgot that in the  ISO_DATE_TIME there are no nanos. You can also use a builder - start from a particular format and add nanos for example. But anyway I am glad it worked for you